# What does 'it' refer to in this example?

Tags: grammar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [It's raining. What is?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5758/its-raining-what-is)

'It is raining.'

What does 'it' refer to?

I know some people might say 'the weather' but you wouldn't say: 'The weather is raining.'

But you would say: How's the weather? It's raining.'

Bit confusing.