# Whence the "it" in "I like it here"?

Tags: pronouns, dummy-it

What is the origin of the use of the object (it) in the following sentences, and what is its purpose?

> I like it here!

and

> Did you like it there?

In essence, the things we are saying we like are really *here* (this place) and *there* (that place) themselves - whence the insertion of the antecedent-free pronoun?

Note: I can think of plenty of antecedents you could replace the "it" with, so that's not the answer I'm looking for.

Comment: Related: [What does “it” refer to in “it's raining”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5758/what-does-it-refer-to-in-its-raining)

Comment: Thanks, @RegDwight Ѭſ道. I tried searching for this question in the database, but you have no idea how common a word "it" is. ^_^

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's called a [dummy it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dummy_pronoun), and according to Wikipedia it's used "when a particular verb argument (or preposition) is nonexistent (it could also be unknown, irrelevant, already understood, or otherwise not to be spoken of directly), but when a reference to the argument (a pronoun) is nevertheless syntactically required."

Answer (score 3):

It’s known as ‘dummy *it*’. It has no antecedent and is meaningless, being used merely to provide an object where otherwise there would be none. It is also found in subject position (‘It’s raining’).