# The general 'it'

Tags: pronouns, dummy-it

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does “it” refer to in “it's raining”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5758/what-does-it-refer-to-in-its-raining) 
>   [Whence the “it” in “I like it here”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/43415/whence-the-it-in-i-like-it-here)

What is the grammatical term for the 'it' in forms such as "It is raining" or "It won't matter", and is there a difference between the usage in those two examples?

Comment: "It's the same the whole world over", to quote the song lyric, but is it?

Comment: Thanks to everyone. I do know that it is a third-person, neuter pronoun. It's the difference between the 'it's in "It is a black dog" and "It is hot in here" that I am querying.
It's oddly difficult to phrase questions about 'it', isn't it.

Answer (score 2):

It's usually called *dummy 'it'* or *empty 'it'*. More accurately, it is a *dummy* subject. It has no meaning, but provides a subject for a clause that otherwise wouldn't have one.

Comment: Thanks. It seems to occur in other languages as well; German is the only one I can comment on with any depth of knowledge at all. 'It' would seem straightforward ... until one starts thinking about 'it'.

Comment: French has 'il pleut'.

Answer (score 1):

It is a [third-person, neuter pronoun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It_%28pronoun%29). I had always assumed it was a definite article, so this was kind of neat to learn as a bit of nerd-trivia.

As for the first example, 'it' is associated with 'is,' so it functions as part of a to-be verb.

Answer (score 0):

*It* is a pronoun and acts as a subject in your examples. There is no difference between the two that I can think of.

Comment: You could also call it **subject pronouns**.