# Is "it makes it easy to do ..." good English?

Tags: grammaticality, phrases, pronouns, dummy-it

There are two "it"s in this sentence, but they refer to different things.  Is this considered good English?  If not, what's a better way to express the same meaning?

Comment: If the sentence is "It makes it easy to do it." _it_ could refer to three distinct things. It's an English sentence, and it can be used.

Answer (score 3):

It is grammatically fine to have two identical pronouns referring to separate [antecedents](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antecedent_%28grammar%29), but it's not necessarily the best way to write:

> I had to clean up the carpet, so I looked in the closet and found a vacuum cleaner. It made it easier to do.

While it's understandable and grammatically valid, **it**'s not the clearest way to say **it**.  It would be better to replace one of the *it*s (choose the one whose antecedent is furthest away, i.e. *cleaning the carpet*), with an appropriate noun or noun phrase:

> I had to clean up the carpet, so I looked in the closet and found a vacuum cleaner. It made **the job** easier to do.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is fine. The first *it* is a "dummy pronoun." It doesn't refer to anything and is there simply as a placeholder for the subject. The second it is, presumably, referential. No problems here.

Comment: I'm not sure that the first *it* is a dummy.  [In *it is raining*, the *it* is certainly a dummy](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/5758/10041), because you're not referring to anything in particular.  But when I read *it makes it easier to do*, I would automatically assume that there are two antecedents.

Comment: I think both 'it's would have referents. What is easier to do? __It__ is easier to do (some _thing_ is easier). What makes it easier to do? __It__ (some _thing_) makes it easier to do. In Daniel's example, the first 'it' is the vacuum cleaner, and the second 'it' is the cleaning of the carpet.

Comment: In this string, either or both of the _it_'s can be dummies, and either or both can be referential. It's just not clear without additional context, since _it makes it easy to do_ is not a constituent but a chunk of one. Since it's been untimely ripp'd from its sentence, it's not clear **what** its structure is. However, whatever its actual structure might be, it's got lots of grammatical parses and so you shouldn't worry about multiple _it_'s. Multiple pronouns, and articles, and quantifiers, and auxiliaries, ... is just the way English does syntax, is all.

Comment: Yes, I can now see them being dummy or referential.