# Do they call this *it* expletive?

Tags: pronouns, pleonasms

Given the example:

> Was it then that I thought of Alan? No, earlier. From the very first wave of panic my mind reached out to him. Yes, even then, in the heart of the fear, there was a still small voice saying, This will change your life. Sometimes that’s **what** *it* takes to bring people together, a crisis, a tragedy. You could say that’s **what** brought David and I together. I would not have been in that place were it not for my crisis.

There are two nominal relative clauses starting with **what**. 
The first one has *it* after what. Do they call this *it* expletive?

Comment: Apparently, you are using *expletive* to mean something other than what it really means. What really did you mean by *expletive*, can you clarify?

Comment: @Kris: I meant to say ‘it’ has no special meaning in the example. Having read the reply below, I thought this kind of use is divided into expletive and dummy-it. And I don’t need to go into great detail, I didn’t try to further answer.

Comment: 'expletive' usually means a curse or taboo word. That's why people are misunderstanding the title. You should edit to change.

Comment: @Mitch - "expletive" in this sense is accepted linguistic terminology (http://www.ling.upenn.edu/~beatrice/syntax-textbook/box-expletives.html) - no need to change it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, they call that use a ***dummy it***.  We have [a bunch of questions about it](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dummy-it). Wikipedia calls it a [*dummy pronoun*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dummy_pronoun):

> A **dummy pronoun**, also called an expletive pronoun or pleonastic pronoun, is a type of pronoun used in non-pro-drop languages, such as English. It is used when a particular verb argument (or preposition) is nonexistent (it could also be unknown, irrelevant, already understood, or otherwise “not to be spoken of directly”), but when a reference to the argument (a pronoun) is nevertheless syntactically required.

However, I don’t see why it would be an expletive, or offensive speech per your original tagging.  John Lawler in a comment below points out that “expletive” is a bit of old-fashioned vocabulary here, and furthermore that there exist several different flavors of “dummy it”.

---

By the way, saying “what brought David and I together” is non-standard. In Standard English, object pronouns are rendered in the oblique not the subject case, so it must be “what brought David and me together”.

Comment: That's what I like to call "the hypercorrective I"....

Comment: [Dummy _it_](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/57519/15299) has often been called "expletive _it_" and "existential _it_", among other names. Goes to show how useful technical labels are. There are several [other type](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/73821/15299)s of "Dummy _it_", by the way.

Comment: @JohnLawler Existential *it* I have heard of. I should look at some POS tags for mechanical syntactic analysers; I know they have a special token type for that one. Remember he has tagged this with the offensive language tag, so I thought he was talking about a !@#$% expletive. :)

Comment: This particular usage of "expletive" is just oldfashioned terminology; nothing offensive about it. It's just a term that was lying around and got used.

Comment: @JohnLawler I don't think it can be referred to with a standalone *expletive* -- we need to say *expletive it* / *existential it* -- without the *it*, it should invariably and unambiguously mean an oath or swear word. Also, it seems the particular sense of *existential it* is possible only in the adjectival use, not as a noun. "Adjective: (of a word or phrase) Serving to fill out a sentence or line of verse."

Comment: ‘Those who condemn [constructions like _what brought David and I together_] simply assume that the case of a pronoun in a coordination must be the same as when it stands alone. Actual usage is in conflict with this assumption.’ Guess who.

Comment: @BarrieEngland Are you claiming this sort of thing is Standard English?

Comment: [The construction] ‘is used by many highly educated people with social prestige in the community; it should be regarded as a variant Standard English form.’ Same source.

Comment: @BarrieEngland It still seems like hypercorrectivism to me; it doesn’t matter if high-prestige people use it in speech, given that high-prestige people (just like anyone else) regularly say all kinds of non-Standard things. Do you have any references for pronouns switching case under conjunction in any of English’s close relatives? Preferably in the written form, not oral.

Comment: So by "no" you mean "yes", since your quote uses *expletive* in the same sense as the OP?

Comment: No, I haven’t, I’m afraid, and I’m not sure it would have much bearing on the matter in any case.

Comment: The authors concerned give their rationale from page 9 (‘Another kind of illegitimate argument . . .’) here: http://www.cambridge.org/assets/linguistics/cgel/chap1.pdf

Comment: @JohnLawler, why do you think the term expletive is old-fashioned?

Comment: @Kris, yes, we can - and as a matter of fact, when you see the term "expletive" in linguistics, my default reading is expletive in the sense of dummy, not invective/swear words.

Comment: If y'all are suggesting (it's a little hard for me to figure out from comments) that the terms "expletive _it_" and "existential _it_" are synonymous, and that they both mean the same thing as the term "dummy _it_", then I'm afraid there's some confusion. Like _tense_ or _passive_ or any number of other terms applied to grammar by people who learned them in grammar school but haven't studied grammar since, these terms are labels that can be stuck on some usage of _it_ to identify it as idiopathic in some sense. In English grammar, "Dummy _it_" is the general term, and there are varieties.

Comment: @JohnLawler Thanks. That makes a lot of sense and clarifies things.

Answer (score 0):

For the "it" example, yes, in a rarely-used sense of the word. I was surprised to find this definition for "expletive" in my Merriam-Webster: "a syllable, word, or phrase inserted to fill a vacancy (as in a sentence or metrical line) without adding to the sense, esp: a word (as *it* in 'make it clear which you prefer') that occupies the position of the subject or object of a verb in normal English word order and anticipates a subsequent word or phrase that supplies the needed meaningful content."

This use of "expletive" is rare; normally it refers to an exclamatory word.

I don't think the "what" example counts as an expletive, though. In that case, "what" is a relative pronoun introducing a subordinate clause. (And it should be "me," not "I," as the direct object of "brought.")