# Sentence analysis for "Who would it benefit you to know, or what type of person would it benefit you to know to grow your business"

Tags: syntactic-analysis

On a rather big (and I guess copy-edited) blog by Chris Brogan, I read this:

> Who would it benefit you to know, or what type of person would it benefit you to know to grow your business.

And I cannot fathom it. I do understand the meaning out of context but I am at loss when it comes to analyzing the whole thing. I guess the "normalized" version would be

> It benefits me to do something

which is incredibly German-sounding to my ears. If this is the underlying phrasing then I still don't understand the function of "it" in the question.

- What grammatical function does the "it" have? Is it an object or a subject or a predicate nominative or even an explicative? And also,
- Shouldn't the question word be "whom"?

Comment: Would it help to think about the grammatical function of "it" in this sentence? As with your example, it's the [existential "it"](http://www.odlt.org/ballast/existential_it.html). As it *"**It** would benefit me to know Chris Brogan, in order to grow my business"*. I think that's General Reference.

Comment: It's an extremely awkward question, **heavily** over-synctactized (Extraposition; Conjunction Reduction; B-Equi; Wh-Question Formation extracted from two clauses down; and more). It's grammatical, but that's about the only thing you can say good about it.

Comment: I think it is a great sentence. :) -- It is fine grammatically, and is often the type of sentence that results after editing. (Maybe the example sentence could end with a question mark.)

Comment: 'It's grammatical, but that's about the only thing you can say good about it.' Priceless. It should be a closevote reason.

Comment: You want to grow your business. What person, or what type of person, could help you with this?

Comment: Or, keeping it slightly closer to the original: “Who(m), or what type of person, should you (get to) know in order to expand your business?”

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sentence could stand as a perfect counterexample to those descriptivists (and they are many, even on this site) who say that *whom* no longer has a place in English.  It is often considered 'too formal', and *who* is used to replace it indiscriminately. Often, as here, this makes it impossible to tell at first sight whether the pronoun stands for a subject or an object, or even to work out what the intended meaning is. But hey, at least it doesn't sound stuffy, right?

A few other points

- Yes, *it benefits you to do something* is a normal phrase. It was becoming archaic, until it was taken up by marketing people. The 'It' is often called a *dummy it*; see, for example, [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/95909/8019).
- *Grow*, in this sense of 'expand', is not wrong, but it grates on many ears, including mine.
- The author has left out a question mark.
- Inserting 'in order' before 'to grow' would be clearer and avoid the unfortunate echo in *know to grow*.
- And any sentence that requires this sort of analysis to make sense of is deeply unkind to the reader, and makes me, at least, suspect the author's communication skills.

Comment: I think this sentence stands as a perfect counterexample to those people prone to writing over-complex sentences.

Comment: I agree with most of what you say, but not about _whom_. For a small number of people it might help to sort out an unnecessarily complicated structure; but for many it would not help at all. (My evidence is that we quite often get questions here about whether to use _whom_ or not where the interrogative is the subject of the embedded clause, but the embedded clause is itself the object of the matrix clause).

Comment: I don’t see what difference ‘whom’ would have made here. There is absolutely no possibility of mistaking it for the subject of anything—it’s quite clear that it’s an oblique form in disguise, as it were.

Comment: There are a couple of problems with your argument, though. The word 'whom' is virtually obsolete as the direct object of a verb. So it doesn't really make sense to say that the writer has "replaced" (indiscriminately or otherwise) the virtually obsolete form with the hugely more common form: rather, the writer had the choice of replacing the common form 'who' with the virtually obsolete form 'whom' but (indiscriminately or deliberately) decided not to.

Comment: The other major problem with your argument is that it *assumes* that speakers actually use the form of the word ('who' vs 'whom') or indeed grammatical analysis generally as a means of distinguishing subject from object. That's not actually necessarily true. It could be that, given this type of sentence with 'who' vs a version with 'whom', speakers discard who vs whom and use other clues to interpret subject/object status of items in the sentence.

Comment: @Neil, “virtually obsolete” are strong words. I frequently use it (in writing; less so in speech), and see it used quite frequently too, even as a direct object. Not nearly as often as ‘who’, of course—enough that I'd label it ‘rare’, but certainly not obsolete.

Comment: I guess you could debate whether it is "rare" or "virtually obsolete". But in any case, I think my point still stands, doesn't it?

Answer (score 4):

*It* is a **dummy subject** when it points forward to a *to...* phrase as in your example.

---

> It benefits me to do something.

This is indeed the intended basic construction, as you say, or the sentence would be meaningless. As to whether it sounds too German, I'll skip that question for now; but I agree that the original sentence is ugly in any case.

> It benefits me to know people.
>
> It gives me great pleasure to announce Lady Ashton.
>
> It suits you to arrive early.
>
> It suits you, to arrive early.
>
> It suits you, arriving early.

In all of these examples, the answer to *what benefits me?, what gives me great pleasure?, what suits you?* is not only *it*, but also the *to...* infinitive. You could rephrase it as *to know / knowing people benefits me*, etc. The reason is that the *to...* infinitival phrase has a very strong connection to the subject of the main verb.

Some would analyse *to...* as the true subject. Others would say *it* is the subject and *to...* an appositional phrase to *it*. In other words, the phrase modifies *it* and expands on it. For comparison, apposition to the subject can also be observed in sentences of this type:

> Her mother likes you, the woman in yellow.

In sentences of the type *it... to...* as in your example, a comma is not normally written. But it is possible, and it even becomes almost mandatory when you replace the infinitive with a gerund, as in *it suits you, arriving early*. A comma is a sign of apposition here.

The word *it* is called a dummy subject, because it functions syntactically as the subject, but it is almost without semantic content and merely serves to point forward to the *to...* phrase.

It should indeed be *whom* in formal language, since it is the object of *know*; but *who* is also often used instead of *whom* in somewhat less formal language.

Comment: So what happens is that we are asking for the direct object of a subordinate infinite clause that in itself is (part of) the subject of the whole sentence and we do that by wrapping the main clause into the subordinate infinitive phrase? This must be one of the weirdest grammatical things I have ever seen. A sublevel element enclosing its own container... English, you are truely crazy

Comment: Could I also say "Him it would benefit me to know."?

Comment: @Emanuel: Yes, more or less. The reason is that interrogative pronouns normally have to be the first word of the sentence: *she likes me => whom does she like?* This phenomenon is so strong that it even applies to very complex sentences, so that *who(m)* is moved to the front no matter what.

Comment: @Emanuel: You could say that. You can start the sentence with *him* if you want to add focus to/on it. But it is obviously uncommon. It is just like *him I saw in the supermarket*.

Comment: This is not really a ‘truly crazy _English_’ thing as such: an exact parallel can be constructed (and would be far less clumsy to boot) in all the Scandinavian languages, too. I presume German and Dutch would both do it just fine as well, but I’m far too shaky in both to say that with any kind of certainty. Would something along the lines of „Wen würde es mir nutzen zu kennen?“ not be grammatical in German? Or would you need an extra pronoun, „Wen würde es mir nutzen _ihn_ zu kennen“?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: Yes, it is possible as well in Dutch and German (I'm not 100 % sure about the exact order in German, but no *ihn*; in Dutch it is much as in English). Latin can do this too (and even more, as with the relative pronoun on Raphael's tombstone: *Ille hic est Raphael: timuit quo sospite vinci rerum magna parens et moriente mori.*). Greek can do it too. But it is less surprising in languages with a more flexible word order. Relative and interrogative pronouns just really love to be in first position.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I am a German native speaker and both suggestions you made are hard to comprehend for me. They might be correct (I doubt it) but they are bad bad bad style. German does not really allow for wrapping the top-level stuff into lower level brackets ... the only feasible way to ask this would be "Wen zu kennen, würde dir helfen" so you have the full subordinate infinitive at the start as a subject. Also, German does not need a dummy "es" here because it only uses it to fill position 1, if that should be empty. Here, it's not empty

Comment: @Cerberus... I am a native speaker and I would consider it impossible. Technically it works but I think 80 % of the population cannot comprehend this at the first read through and editors and teachers would mark it and have it rephrased.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet... I forgot to mention... the second version (with the ihn) is definitely wrong

Comment: @Emanuel: Well, it's not that different in English! It's ugly and hard to parse at a glance. As to *es*, how about something like *Es gefällt mir nicht, sie zu nehmen*? And *Es gefällt mir nicht, dass er auszieht*. All dummy subjects.

Comment: @Cerberus.. it's only there to fill the position though... "Mir gefällt nicht, dass er sich auszieht"... now it's gone.

Comment: @Emanuel: ...which is the same as in English: *it* "fills up the position" of subject, i.e. it is a dummy subject. A very common phenomenon in the Indo-European languages.

Answer (score 1):

> “Who would it benefit you to know, or what type of person would it benefit you to know to grow your business."

*

I'm a AmE speaker, and I find nothing wrong with that sentence. (Except maybe it could use a question mark, but that will probably depend on the context.)

As I said earlier, via a quick comment onto the OP's post, I think the example sentence is fine and is often the type of sentence that results after editing. You'll find sentences like that in printed books and magazines, and in novels, a lot.

There isn't too much going on, imo, as I didn't have much difficulty in parsing it grammatically, nor in figuring out its meaning.

Let's look at it grammatically, well, at least for a few steps. Here's the original:

- 1.) Who would it benefit you to know, or what type of person would it benefit you to know to grow your business.

The top-level clauses are in the form of interrogative clauses. Let's fiddle with them a bit in order to get similar clauses which have the interrogative words and phrases in situ:

- 2.) It would benefit you to know [*who*], or it would benefit you to know  [*what type of person*] to grow your business.

Each of those coordinate clauses are quite normal and unsurprising:

- It would benefit you to know *who*?
- It would benefit you to know *what type of person* to grow your business?

It is also quite common to often prefer the nominative "who" over the accusative "whom" when that "who/whom" is fronted. Thus,

- *Who* would it benefit you to know?

I don't think you'd want a more in depth grammatical analysis of the structure of your example sentence. But if you do, go ahead and ask and I'm sure someone will help you out.

.

EDITED: To answer your question about the function of "it" -- The "it" in each of those clauses is the grammatical subject.