# Listen to it rain and look at it snow

Tags: expressions

Do the following sentences make sense and are they used commonly?

1) Listen to it rain.
2) Look at it snow.

Comment: What exactly is your concern? Is there a word that bothers you? Yes, those phrases make sense and are used.

Comment: The use of "it" like that is likely confusing to someone learning English.  But those are perfectly valid English sentences.

Comment: How about the following? 1) Listen to it raining. 2) Look at it snowing.

Comment: Yup, "Watch it snow" and "Watch it snowing" are equivalent and equally acceptable sentences.  Strange, though, that you can say, "it is snowing", but not "it is snow" (that would mean that thing over there, the pile of white stuff, is snow).

Comment: (1) [Sense verbs](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/96744/15299) like _listen_ and _look_ can take either infinitives without _to_ -- _listen to it rain_ or gerunds -- _listen to it raining_. (2) The weather verbs _rain, snow, hail,_ etc. have [dummy _it_ subjects](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/95947/15299).

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understand the question, but perhaps [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/5763/4040) will answer it:

> Definitions for *it* in my *Webster's 3rd New International
>   Dictionary* include:
>
> > **2a** used as an expletive subject of an
> >     impersonal verb that expresses a
> >     simple condition or an action without
> >     implied reference to an agent about
> >     the weather ... or time.
>
> *It is raining* or *It is two o'clock* are examples of 2a.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, both phrases are common (at least in New England, where snow is common. Not so much in Florida.) The distinction is that a heavy rain is distinctly audible, particularly on a hard surface such as a roof,  while snow falling is essentially silent, so one looks at snow and listens to rain.

Also, individual snowflakes are larger and more visible than raindrops, and fall quite slowly, while raindrops fall quite quickly and are hard to see.

Comment: Of course when it does snow in Florida, people are more likely to make a big deal out of watching or looking at it.