# Is it OK to use "it" to refer to human beings?

Tags: grammar

In my understanding, "it" can only be used to refer to objects other than human beings. However, I just found a sentence as follow from a book.

> It is Mr. Kenta who came at 8 this morning.

Is it grammatically correct?

Comment: This has been addressed here before. This is the non-referential 'it' as in 'It's us' and (as 'weather it') in 'It's raining / windy / snowy' etc. Often ce in French. So this _it_ is not really 'referring to a human being'; it's a grammatical place-holder. Covered by John Lawler at 'What do the pronouns indicate?'

Comment: Also see [What does "it" refer to in "it's raining"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5758/what-does-it-refer-to-in-its-raining)