# While it is raining- Clause

Tags: clauses

I was studying about clauses in a book and then a sentence came which seemed pretty abstruse to me.

The book says that in the sentence: "We can't start while it is raining," the "while it is raining" part forms a clause.

Can anybody please tell me what the subject of this clause is? Is it 'it' or 'while'. Kindly provide explanation too so that I can understand it well.

Comment: Please see [what does ‘it’ refer to in ‘it’s raining’?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5758/what-does-it-refer-to-in-its-raining)

Comment: The analysis of "while it is raining" is quite problematic. One solution is to treat it as a preposition phrase with "while" as head and a subordinate content clause ("it is raining") as complement. Whichever way it is analysed, the subject is clearly "it".

Comment: 'We can't start _during  raining_' makes it clearer that it is a preposition phrase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the book says 'while it is raining' is a clause, it actually means 'it is raining' is a clause, without 'while'.

> We can't start **while it is raining**.

Means:

> We can't start **during the time it is raining**.

Just as you can't say 'during the time it is raining' is a clause, neither can you say 'while it is raining' is a clause.

Comment: If "while" is treated as a subordinating conjunction, then "while it is raining" is a clause introduced by the subordinator "while". For those (like me) who treat "while" as a preposition, then the clause is "it is raining".

Answer (score 2):

*While it is raining* is really a clause with the subject *it* and the predicate *is raining*. *While* is a conjunction here, so it cannot be the subject. It only connects the main clause (we can't start) with the subordinate clause (it is raining).

Here are more examples of sentences with time clauses (time clauses are used to indicate the time when an event in the main clause takes place) (the subject of the sub-clause is **in bold**):

1. As soon as **you** arrive, give me a call.
2. I read it while **you** were drying your hair.
3. I went there when **I** was a child.