# How do you explain the usage of "it" in the sentences below?

Tags: grammaticality, syntactic-analysis, word-order

Could you explain the usage of ***it*** in the following sentences?

1. I don't like **it**  when you speak like this.
2. I hate **it** when you speak like this.
3. I know **it** for certain that he is in town now.
4. He owes **it** to his brother that he became a research chemist.

Comment: In 2) the **it** should be removed.

Comment: ok. why? in my book there is "it" in the second one. and why do we need "it" in other sentences?

Comment: This is the so-called "dummy *it*". In certain situations it is necessary because that's how English grammar works. You can't omit certainl things that you can omit in other grammars. Like, in Russian you can just say "Темнеет" or "На улице мороз", but in English you have to say "It is getting dark" or "It is cold outside" instead. That's the same dummy *it*. It's called dummy precisely because it doesn't really refer to anything, its purpose is syntactical, not sematic. That said, in your example 2 the dummy *it* is optional, and in example 1 it can be optional depending on what comes after.

Comment: See [Dummy pronoun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dummy_pronoun) on Wikipedia, or check out ["What does *it* refer to in *it's raining*?"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5758/what-does-it-refer-to-in-its-raining)

Comment: @RegDwigнt This is completely diffeent from weather-it though!! See below in about 20 mins ...

Comment: @Robusto C'mon lad. Read the comment above!!! This is NOT weather *it*.

Comment: @Araucaria Sure, take it from here, if you feel like it, I am obviously providing a simplified explanation tailored to just one person, rather than an actual answer for the site as a whole. Which is why it's not an answer, but a comment.

Comment: This is one of those things where the academic answer can be interesting and pretty and span a dissertation, but that you can't actually learn from that academic answer. This is something sofyaorel has to gradually develop a hunch for, by immersing herself in the language. Just like any native speaker has to. They never learned any rules, either. After a while it will come naturally.

Comment: @RegDwigнt I did a simple one here! :-)

Comment: It's like [this](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0018033/?ref_=fn_al_tt_3).

Comment: @HotLicks That's definitely a referential pronoun!

Comment: Or maybe [this](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0099864/?ref_=nv_sr_5) is it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1) and (2) are a different construction from (3) and (4).

Note that the subordinate clauses in the first two are adverbial and can be preposed

- *When you speak like this, I don't like it.*
- *When you speak like this, I hate it.*

The *it* in these sentences is referential, an indefinite direct object required by the transitive verbs *like* and *hate*. The position of the clause is irrelevant.

(3) and (4) are not adverbial clauses, but extraposed complements, as @Araucaria says. The *it* in this case is the usual dummy *it* of Extraposition. It's unusual that Extraposition is applied to direct objects instead of subjects. Indeed, I find (3) with *it* ungrammatical, but just fine without *it*; YMMV, of course. But (4) is fine, in fact almost unavoidable, given the complex set of presuppositions involved.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes it is difficult to processs a clause when it functions as the Complement of a particular type of verb. Other times, we want to delay the Complement of the verb when it is a clause to give it greater prominence at the end of the sentence. In both such circumstances, we use the dummy pronoun *it* as the Complement of the verb and shunt the smaller clause down to the end of the sentence  where it appears as an Extraposed Complement.

The Original Poster's sentences could be paraphrased like this:

1. I don't like [when you speak like this].
2. I hate [when you speak like this].
3. I know  [that he is in town now] for certain .
4. He owes [that he became a research chemist] to his brother .

Whether the *when*-strings there are clauses or not is a bit controversial, but they definitely work the same way as clauses.